# Re-create platform_www folder?

Tags: cordova

Somehow I messed up `platform_www` folder in both platforms I use (Android and Browser).

I tried using `cordova prepare` to fix the issue, but this copies files from `platform_www` to `www`.

How can one tell cordova-cli to update (overwrite) `platform_www` folders on all platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove and add the platform again.

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova platform remove browser
ionic cordova platform add browser
```

Comment: Yep, eventually, this was the only option as only then are the files generated..